# additional parameters for layer in sequential model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, keras-layer, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to use a new layer in the sequential model, however, the layer needs some additional input. When the model is not sequential. The model is like

```
X_in = Input(shape=(X.shape[1],))    
H = Dropout(0.5)(X_in)
H = GraphConvolution(16, support, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(5e-4))([H]+[G])
H = Dropout(0.5)(H)
Y = GraphConvolution(y.shape[1], support, activation='softmax')([H]+[G])
model = Model(inputs=[X_in]+[G], outputs=Y)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01))
```

I tried to use sequential() function like below, but don't know how to add a layer in this way.

```
model2 = Sequential()
batch_size = 5
model2.add(Dropout(0.5, input_shape=(X.shape[0], X.shape[1])))
```

I also tried to create input sequence and call the GraphConvolution at different timestamp independently.
I tried

```
input_sequences = Input(shape=(X.shape[0], X.shape[1]))
```

Also

```
input_sequences = Input(shape=(batch_size, X.shape[0], X.shape[1]),batch_shape=(None, None, None))
```

But I really don't know how to then process each input of the input sequence independently. Because the `input_sequences.shape[0] = None`

The problem is pretty straightforward and I have encountered the same problem many times. Thanks a lot in advance, any answers are welcome.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I have got some solution but not so straightforward. I am using batch_shape in the Input function:

```
with tf.name_scope('input_sequence'):
    input_sequences = Input(batch_shape=(X.shape[0], timestamps, X.shape[1]))
    gcn_output = []

    for i in range(timestamps):
        gcn_output.append(tf.expand_dims(model([input_sequences[:,i,:]]+[G]),1))
    gcn_output_tensor = tf.concat(
        gcn_output,
        axis=1,
        name='concat'
    )
```

Comment: Using `batch_input_shape` seems to be the most convenient solution to your problem.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Thank you!

Comment: @MarcinMożejko do you know how to improve the process of processing the input at each time stamp and concatenate them? My current implementation uses a list and then concat, which looks not that straightforward...Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem and I still don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use input_sequences = Input(batch_shape=(X.shape[0], timestamps, X.shape[1]))